# Installed AMD graphics driver after reboot cant login or open terminal

Tags: drivers, graphics, login, amd-graphics

I downloaded the driver from here: https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Driver-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx
Followed the installation instructions and everything went well.

Upon reboot, I am unable to login to my account or the guest account.
I cant open the terminal with any control alt F command.

Running Ubuntu 16.04, Radeon HD8670M

What can I try next to fix this?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's a newer version of this driver, 17.50. You should try this one, but I honestly don't think it will make any difference. The AMDGPU-Pro driver is known for causing severe system problems on Ubuntu (and probably most other Linux distros), even if you're running the LTS version (the one AMD uses to test their drivers). I personally gave up trying to install it, and there are many benchmarks on the internet showing you're very well served with the open-source drivers.

Comment: I was finally able to open a shell in recovery mode and removed the driver. Thanks for the tip about the open source drivers.